# Change ArrayList data in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, dynamic, arraylist

I need to create many alarms, so I need a list view which contains items with a DatePicker, a TimePicker and a Delete Button. I have tried various way but I have not found a solution to this issue:

I want to be able to change the data in the DatePicker or TimePicker, which will change the data in an ArrayList for the corresponding Alarm. To do this however, I will need position, but as it is not final I cannot use it to access the Alarm in the ArrayList from my Adapter.

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: you need to give a bit more details...

Comment: @TacB0sS What do you need?

Comment: some code example... if final is your problem, sometimes I use duplicate local variable for the anonymous class... but that is dirty, I would define a class which gets the proper value in its constructor, or simply click 'Ctrl + 1' on the anonymous class Eclipse would take care of the rest

Comment: @TacB0sS I'm not sure what code I can offer. I have given a clear specification of what I need to achieve, but I don't know how to achieve it. All I need is some kind of pseudo-code or guidance on how to go about my problem.